# How do I put data from csv column that i already split into different rows in csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file with a column that contain a lots of sentences, i have split the sentences by ".", and i wanted to put the separated sentences into different rows in a new csv file. Below are the some of my codes.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

excel= pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
excel.dropna(inplace = True) 
split = pd.DataFrame(excel["months_readmore_story"].str.split('.'), columns=['sentences'])

split.to_csv('split.csv')
```

I tried the above code, but there is nothing in the new csv file. This is from the original csv file, file.csv

```
file.csv
id      date         months_readmore_story
1        sep 20       England. The weather caused a lots of uproar.
2        Aug 10       Health. Health have been an issue.
```

The output i wanted in split.csv

```
split.csv
story_id        sentences_id      sentences
 1               1                 England
 1               2                 The weather caused a lots of uproar
 2               3                 Health
 2               4                 Health have been an issue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
df['temp'] =df[' months_readmore_story'].str.rstrip('.').str.split('.').values.tolist()
df= df[['id', 'temp']]
df.set_index('id')['temp'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'temp'})
```

O/P:

```
   id                                  temp
0   1                               England
1   1   The weather caused a lots of uproar
0   2                                Health
1   2             Health have been an issue
```

Comment: i got this error instead, TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'

Comment: i wanted the split sentences to be in different rows, but i did not get that using your solution

Comment: i already tried the updated solution, and the split sentences are not in different rows, but instead they are scattered everywhere

Comment: i am using data from file.csv, and i wanted the split sentences in different rows to be put in a new csv, i can't seem to use your solution

Comment: ah! it worked, i forgot to change some parts and had to include some extra code. If i may ask, is it possible if include exception, for statistics, like 5.35 percent will not be split

Answer (score 1):

hope this will work.assume your original dataframe as `df`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.months_readmore_story.str.split('.').tolist(),index=df.id).stack()
new_df = new_df.reset_index([0, 'id'])
new_df.columns = ['story_id', 'sentences']
new_df['sentences'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
new_df.dropna(subset=['sentences'], inplace=True)
new_df.insert(1,"sentences_id",range(1,(new_df.shape[0]+1)))
```

Comment: this solution might work if the data frame is already listed instead of retrieved from a csv file, because i can't seem to be able to use it.

Comment: I have tested it with using  file.csv output (as mentioned in the question) as a dataframe.it worked as expected.you get the same result as mentioned above  when read the csv file to a dataframe?